# Pan and Zoom stage on Action Script 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am trying to create zoom and pan option on Action Script 2. I want to do it on stage not on movieclips. I have done a basic coding but I would like to create drag and zoom option. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code. I have two Movie Clips on the stage zoom in and out to zoom in and out the stage

```
zoom_mc.onPress = function() {
    var zinxpos:Number;
    var zinypos:Number;
    zinxpos=zoom_mc._x;
    zinypos=zoom_mc._y;
    zoom_mc.onEnterFrame = function() {
    Mouse.hide();
    this._x = _root._xmouse;
    this._y = _root._ymouse;
    }   
    _root.onMouseDown = function() {
    this._xscale+=10;
    this._yscale+=10;
}
}

zoomout_mc.onPress = function() {   
    zoom_mc._x=zinxpos;
    zoom_mc._y=zinypos;
    zoomout_mc.onEnterFrame = function() {
    Mouse.hide();
    this._x = _root._xmouse;
    this._y = _root._ymouse;
    }   
    _root.onMouseDown = function() {
    this._xscale-=10;
    this._yscale-=10;
}
}
```

Comment: The better option would be to use a movieclip of same size as stage. Use the MC as container of all your content and then put stage-size **mask** above it (new layer). Now you can expand size of content MC (appears to zoom in / enlarge) or you can change the **x** or **y** position of content MC to simulate panning. The content MC is visible only through the mask (since mask is canvas/stage size) where this will simulate the zoom/pan effects you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
var $stage = this;
var isDragging = false;
var mouseDownX = 0;
var mouseDownY = 0;

$stage.onEnterFrame = function() {      
    if(isDragging){
        $stage._x += $stage._xmouse - mouseDownX;
        $stage._y += $stage._ymouse - mouseDownY;
    }       
} 

$stage.onMouseDown = function() {   
    isDragging = true;
    mouseDownX = $stage._xmouse;
    mouseDownY = $stage._ymouse;
}

$stage.onMouseUp = function() { 
    isDragging = false;
}

zoom_mc.onPress = function() {
   $stage._xscale += 10;
   $stage._yscale += 10;
}

zoomout_mc.onPress = function() {   
   $stage._xscale -= 10;
   $stage._yscale -= 10;    
}
```